# php file_get_contents giving error

Tags: php, json, http

When I run the following query on browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8096/solr/select/?q=june 17&amp;start=0&amp;rows=8&amp;indent=on&amp;hl=on&amp;hl.fl=Data&amp;wt=json
```

I get results. No problems. Notice that there is a space between june and 17

However when I receive that query in my PHP i.e. $q=June 17 I use

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1:8096/solr/select/?q=$q&start=0&rows=8&indent=on&hl=on&hl.fl=Data&wt=json";
$json_O=json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
```

After this I see the following on my firebug:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:8096/solr/select/?q=june 17&amp;start=0&amp;rows=8&amp;indent=on&amp;hl=on&amp;hl.fl=Data&amp;wt=json) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

However note that if there is no space between my query words (I mean if it is a single word) then everything is perfect.

Why does it work fine when I issue exactly same query on browser as compared to file_get_contents(). Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in the `q` parameter's value. Could be that. Try `urlencode()`ing the parameter.

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1:8096/solr/select/?q=".urlencode($q)."&start=0&rows=8&indent=on&hl=on&hl.fl=Data&wt=json";

$json_O=json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
```

Comment: Thanks Nadh. I was using urlencode but probably not in right place. Your code snippet worked. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

This is, because the `file_get_contents` function sends a request to a web server in HTTP, which looks like this

```
GET /solr/select/?q=bla HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1
...[more headers here]...
```

Note, that there is a the in HTTP version specified in the request (`HTTP/1.0`)

Now, if there is a space in your request string, you send something like

```
GET /solr/select/?q=bla foo HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1
...[more headers here]...
```

Your server seems to parse `foo` as the version and returns `505 HTTP Version Not Supported`. If you encode the space in the string (e.g. by replacing it with `%20`, this should not happen).